# Postgres: Problem INSERTING records if they does not exist already in a table

Tags: sql, database, subquery

I've two tables:

Temporal Table: planning.env_seleccion_envase seleccionado_temp (Updates one time every day and by now has  500 records)

Productive Table: planning.env_seleccion_envase_seleccionado (Consolidate the data from all the year and by now has 0 records)

In order to insert just the new records from the temporal table to the productive table I made a query, here is my try:

```
INSERT INTO planning.env_seleccion_envase_seleccionado(centro, sku, texto_breve_material, movimiento, almacen, cantidad, unidad_medida_base, fecha_contabilizacion, fecha_entrada, sag, uen, drv, cupo, tipo_envase, cupo_agrupado, color_envase, cantidad_abs, fecha_carga) 
    SELECT DISTINCT centro, sku, texto_breve_material, movimiento, almacen, cantidad, unidad_medida_base, fecha_contabilizacion, fecha_entrada, sag, uen, drv, cupo, tipo_envase, cupo_agrupado, color_envase, cantidad_abs, fecha_carga
    FROM planning.env_seleccion_envase_seleccionado
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 'X' 
        FROM planning.env_seleccion_envase_seleccionado_temp
        WHERE 
            planning.env_seleccion_envase_seleccionado_temp.fecha_carga = 
            planning.env_seleccion_envase_seleccionado.fecha_carga
    );
```

I'm using just the field **FECHA_CARGA** as comparative, because this field has the date of the record insert, also I tried to used all the fields from the table in the "**Where**" section of the query but it did not work either.

In both cases I get the result of ** INSERT 0 0 ** and it just insert nothing

Can you help me guys? Any ideas? Sorry if the solution is bovious but i'm a little bit new

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
insert into
  usuario(id, email)
select
  nextval('seq_usuario'),
  'email@gmail.com'
where
  NOT EXISTS (
    select
      id,
      email
    from
      usuario
    where
      email like 'email@gmail.com'
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

you are inserting from product table , it should be from temp table and checking on the temp table:

```
INSERT INTO planning.env_seleccion_envase_seleccionado(centro, sku, texto_breve_material, movimiento, almacen, cantidad, unidad_medida_base, fecha_contabilizacion, fecha_entrada, sag, uen, drv, cupo, tipo_envase, cupo_agrupado, color_envase, cantidad_abs, fecha_carga) 
SELECT DISTINCT centro, sku, texto_breve_material, movimiento, almacen, cantidad, unidad_medida_base, fecha_contabilizacion, fecha_entrada, sag, uen, drv, cupo, tipo_envase, cupo_agrupado, color_envase, cantidad_abs, fecha_carga
FROM    
    planning.env_seleccion_envase_seleccionado_temp  --<-- here
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT
            'X'
        FROM
            planning.env_seleccion_envase_seleccionado --<-- here
        WHERE
            planning.env_seleccion_envase_seleccionado_temp.fecha_carga = planning.env_seleccion_envase_seleccionado.fecha_carga
    );
```